# Including common code in header/footer with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have common functions and formats to most of my scripts.  Each script brings up a window for me to paste workstations and it performs basic tasks like checking connectivity before proceeding.  Generally, I copy and paste this code and modify the body.  What I would like to do is include a header and footer, but I get  "Missing closing '}' in statement block." errors.  Example:

```
<# Begin Header #>
if($canceled) {
    write-host "Operation canceled."
}
else {
    if($computers.length -gt 0) {
        [array]$computers = $computers.split("`n").trim()

        # Loop through computers entered
        foreach($pc in $computers) {
            # Skip zero length lines for computers
            if(($pc.length -eq $null) -OR ($pc.length -lt 1)) {
                continue
            }
            else {
                # Try to connect to the computer, otherwise error and continue
                write-host "Connecting to: $pc$hr"
                if(test-connection -computername $pc -count 1 -ea 0) {
                    <# End Header #>

                    Body of script

                    <# Begin Footer #>
                }
                else {
                    utc # Unable to contact
                }
            }
            write-host "`n"
        }
    }
}
<# End Footer #>
```

Rather than copying/pasting each time, I would prefer to do this...

."c:\scripts\header.ps1"

-- code --

."c:\scripts\footer.ps1"

Is that even possible when the header ends with an open bracket?  I do this in PHP but I can't figure out a work-around in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach could be changed into storing a function in one file and your custom script that runs for-each server in another. You can store a scriptblock to a variable in PowerShell and pass that as a parameter to a function. You can use `Invoke-Command -scriptblock $Variable` to execute that code.

Write your function like this:

```
function runAgainstServerList {
    param ( [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock) 
    if($canceled) {
        write-host "Operation canceled."
    }
    else {
        if($computers.length -gt 0) {
            [array]$computers = $computers.split("`n").trim()

            # Loop through computers entered
            foreach($pc in $computers) {
                # Skip zero length lines for computers
                if(($pc.length -eq $null) -OR ($pc.length -lt 1)) {
                    continue
                }
                else {
                    # Try to connect to the computer, otherwise error and continue
                    write-host "Connecting to: $pc$hr"
                    if(test-connection -computername $pc -count 1 -ea 0) {

                        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock

                    }
                    else {
                        utc # Unable to contact
                    }
                }
                write-host "`n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now save that off to your include file like 'myFunctions.ps1'

Then create your custom script that you want to run per server like this:

```
. myFunctions.ps1

[ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlockToPass = {
     ## Insert custom code here
}

runAgainstServerList $ScriptBlockToPass
```

To get you a step closer to what might be your end goal, You may want to append the `-ComputerName "ComputerNameHere"` argument to your `invoke-command` statement inside your included function. This would cause your script to be executed on the remote system instead of locally.